# SharePoint 2003 Project Tracking - Milestones

Tags: custom-list

I have created a project tracking - milestone custom list, which has a dropdown list for project, but I do not see anyway to populate the dropdown list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is this really SharePoint 2003 (WSS 2.0)? Or is that a typo? Also, what type of field is "project"?

Comment: I am told we are running SharePoint 2003 (WSS 3.0), the project field was created by SharePoint as a default when I create a "Project Tracking - Project Milestone list", but when I go to site settings and select the project column I do not see a way for me to populate the list, I could just create a new project column but was wondering if this default column is supposed to be linked into other sites, example project tasks

Comment: I am still confused. WSS 3.0 is SharePoint 2007, WSS 2.0 is SharePoint 2003. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288501(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: When you go into settings what *type* of field does it say the project field is? Is it a lookup?

Answer (score 0):

If this is WSS 3.0 and the project field is a lookup, it is looking up the values from another list.

From the project tracking list go to list settings

[image]

Then click on the project field. You should see something like this.

[image]

Then you will need to go back to the main page for the site. Look on the left where the quick launch is. Find "View All Site Content". Find the list that was named in the lookup and you will be able to add new options/edit existing options there.